# Avoid PDOException while connecting to an external database

Tags: database

I'm trying to connect to another database (not related to drupal) in drupal to show extra info. This database server could be down and is not a problem, if it's the case I don't want to show the info with no errors, maybe an info message that is now available at this moment.

I setted up the settings.php correctly with the database credentials, and when the database is up, everything is ok.

I use the next code

```
  db_set_active('external');
  $query = db_select('extra_info', 'i');
  ...
```

If the database is down, the db_select() fails and throws an PDOException. The problem is the website is down in that case, shows the error and so on. I tryed to sorround it in a try catch.

```
  try {
      db_set_active('external');
      $query = db_select('extra_info', 'i');
      ...
  }
  catch (PDOException $e) {
      // Ok.. is not a problem
  }
```

I don't know if there is a way to check if the database connection is ok first and then do the select or do nothing if is there is a problem and continue showing the website.
I tried the isActiveConnection() function, but I think is not what I need.

Thanks.

**EDIT: The solution to my problem is to use db_set_active() back to default.**

```
  try {
      db_set_active('external');
      $query = db_select('extra_info', 'i');
      ...
      db_set_active(); // This won't be executed!
  }
  catch (PDOException $e) {
      // Ok.. is not a problem
      db_set_active(); // Needed!
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

issue is that db_set_active just sets active key in some array and doesn't do any connection. when you do db_select or any other query only then it connects.

your second code is good. also you could do something like this:

```
  db_set_active('external');
  try {
   //check connection
   db_select("select 1");
  }
  catch (PDOException $e) {
      //error. set default back
      db_set_active('default');
  }
```

as you know how to check if connection is there now you just need extra logic what todo when connection cannot be established

Comment: Thanks @MantasKaranauskas I was getting an Uncaught exception 'PDOException' because I forgot to add db_set_active() in the catch section.

I updated the first post with the solution to my specific problem.

Comment: To test connection, `select 1 from dual` or simply `select 1` is safer as it does not require any particular table to exist to work. [See description of DUAL pseudotable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUAL_table).